# Reading date from git.properties using gitProperties.get()

Tags: spring-boot, git-commit

have a git commit id plugin in a boot application.
When i try to read the build.time from the git.properties file, it returns as a String, any way we can retrieve it as date ?

```
gitProperties.get("build.time");
```

this prints in milliseconds, i can convert this to seconds, using Instant, but  is there a more direct way ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other direct way of doing this as [plugin documentation](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin) says that

dateFormat - (default: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ) is a normal SimpleDateFormat String and will be used to represent git.build.time and git.commit.time and you can convert using user wanted format using simple date formats.